# How do you mock generic types in a type-safe manner?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Are there more type-safe alternatives to this (other than mocking a non-generic subtype of a generic type)?

```java
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void test() {
    GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument> genericType = mock(GenericType.class);
    // the rest of the test
}
```

A more concrete example:

```java
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void getHeadersFilter_ifNull_delegatesToInjectedObjectProvider() {
    HttpHeadersFilter filterMock = mock(HttpHeadersFilter.class);
    // this line includes an unchecked cast   
    ObjectProvider<List<HttpHeadersFilter>> headersFiltersProviderMock = mock(ObjectProvider.class);
    given(headersFiltersProviderMock.getIfAvailable()).willReturn(List.of(filterMock));
    // the rest of the test
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what the generic type does?

Comment: Assuming this is Spring, [`HttpHeadersFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/headers/HttpHeadersFilter.java) does not seem generic. Maybe also use `MockServerHttpRequest`? `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` might not help much.

Comment: @MartinZeitler `ObjectProvider` is generic

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of Mockito have "magic" `mock()` method that can infer the Mock's type automatically:

```
final GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument> genericType = mock();
```

This method overload actually accepts a varargs array (with zero elements in this specific case). The type of the array can be picked up by the compiler, even if no actual arguments have been provided.

---

Alternatives:

- `final GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument> genericType = Mockito.<GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument>>mock(GenericType.class);`
- `final GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument> genericType = mock(new TypeToken<GenericType<ImportantTypeArgument>>(){}.getRawType());`

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Why do other libraries require `Class<T>` or `new TypeReference<>()` if it was possible with the in-built type inference all along?

Comment: @Powet Because it is a very ugly hack and does not work in all cases (and sometimes it even infers the wrong type). It might not always be possible to accept a varargs array which must be the last parameter (and it is very confusing to have it in a method's signature). Furthermore, this will only work for a single generic type parameter; as soon as you have multiple type parameters, this hack won't help.

Comment: Also, is it *type-safe* after all if arrays are involved?

Comment: @Powet what do you mean? Generics are a compile-time construct, they are erased during compilation and no longer exist at runtime. The returned mocked object (`GenericType<T> mock = mock();`) is indistinguishable from the one returned by `GenericType<T> mock = mock(GenericType.class)`.